# how can i scale and translate cubes faces and edge in three.js

Tags: three.js, resize, modeling, cube, edges

Is there a way to resize the edges and faces of objects like cubes in three.js?

For example, I want to build the shape you see below without using Blender or a modelling tool. I want to scale the edge and faces of the cube to make the sharp edges as you see below.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Could you provide a 3D representation of what you want?

Comment: Is that 2d? You can do it with splines and extrude if you need.

Comment: thank you so much guys , what i'm trying to build is a cube that has 4 pyramids in its four vertices in 3d using three.js . as you can see in the image above ,,, i don't have a 3d example yet